# Sublime Automatic Build Selector

Tags: latex, sublimetext

My current custom LaTeX sublime build goes:

```
{
"path":"/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/bin",
"cmd": ["sh", "-c", "pdflatex main.tex && open main.pdf"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": ["source.latex"],
}
```

And it's working great when I select it manually. However, I'm switching back and forth between python scripts and my latex code, so I want to set the build system to "automatic" and let Sublime know that it needs to run LaTeX for .tex files. I tried source.tex, source.latex, source.LaTeX... I think I'm barking up the wrong tree.

**edit:** I found out that by pressing Cmd+Alt+P I get some information about what the Syntax Highlighter is aware of. It seems to suggest that the right selector would be `text.tex.latex`... but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just using `"selector": "text.tex.latex"`, without the square brackets? Worked for me.